# How to use Variants with Framer Motion useAnimation

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I need my animation to show when it reaches viewport with this logic below from stack overflow:

```js
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";

const Component = () => {
    const animation = useAnimation();    
    const [ref, inView, entry] = useInView({ threshold: 0.1 });

    useEffect(() => {
      if (inView) {
        animation.start("visible");
      } else {
        animation.start("hidden");
      }
    }, [animation, inView]);

    const variants = {
        visible: {
          y: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          transition: { duration: 0.5, delayChilden: 0.2, staggerChildren: 0.1 },
        },
        hidden: {
          y: enter,
          opacity: 0,
        },
    }
    return (
<>
        <motion.div
          ref={ref}
          animate={animation}
          initial="hidden"
          variants={{variants}}>TITLE 1</motion.div>
//---------CONTENTS HERE
        <motion.div
          ref={ref}
          animate={animation}
          initial="hidden"
          variants={{variants}}>TITLE 2</motion.div>
//---------CONTENTS HERE
       <motion.div
        ref={ref}
        animate={animation}
        initial="hidden"
        variants={{variants}}>TITLE 3</motion.div>
</>
      );
}
```

But using variants to reuse animation for different headings, the animation loads no longer until I reach the last heading of the page

I thought of having different variants for each title but that would just make my code messy.
How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the way to do this, all you have to do is have as many useAnimation and inView needed for the number of elements you are going to apply
In my case, that's 3 useAnimation & inView for 3 titles

```js
const title1 = useAnimation()
  const title2 = useAnimation()
  const title3 = useAnimation()

  const [ref, inView, entry] = useInView({ threshold: 0.5 });
  const [ref1, inView2] = useInView({ threshold: 0.5 });
useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      animation.start("visible")
    } else {
      animation.start("hidden");
    }

    if (inView2) {
      animation2.start("visible")
    } else {
      animation2.start("hidden");
    }
  }, [inView, inView2]);
```

Voila